# How to set the list of options in JSHint?

Tags: javascript, jshint

I want to suppress some warnings/errors in JSHint. In the document it says to pass it as an argument, but I am a bit confused.

```
source = "...."; // JavaScript source content
var success = JSHINT(source, options, globals);
```

For example, I want to suppress both "smarttabs" and "evil". How do I do that?

Comment: How are you running JSHint? The snippet you've posted in your question is for when you are calling it yourself in a script.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.jshint.com/docs/config/

Just supply directive comments like these, and jshint will adapt:

```
/* jshint undef: true, unused: true */
/* global MY_GLOBAL */
```

(Also, you can go through the link above to see more configuration options, such as creating a JSON literal to configure jshint's behavior).

Comment: So, where do I put this "comments"? Can it be anywhere in the HTML page?

Comment: Put it at the beginning of your js script.